# Get taxonomy fields on node.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy attached to my nodes. The taxonomy has an extra image field attached to it. I can find the taxonomy title field at:

```
$content['field_news_outlet'][0]['#title']
```

but I can't seem to find the image field I attached to this taxonomy.

If I check with kpr() or dpm():

```
$term=taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$value=field_get_items('taxonomy_term',$term,'field_news_outlet_logo');
```

I can see the field name there but the image uri doesn't seem to appear anywhere in there. The only image uri I can find is the one for the site's logo.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I hardcoded $tid as 1 in my template file.